# Using pyinstaller to make an executable file from python .py file utilizing Pandas to read a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter, pyinstaller

In my python file, the "df = pd.read_csv('table.csv')" bit causes a FileNotFoundError even though it resides in the same directory. I run my executable file that I built with pyinstaller.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('table.csv')
```

When I attempt to build the exe with pyinstaller I use the following code in terminal:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'table.csv:.' gui_calc.py
```

When I run the executable file...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui_calc.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "pandas/io/parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
  File "pandas/io/parsers.py", line 452, in _read
  File "pandas/io/parsers.py", line 936, in __init__
  File "pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1168, in _make_engine
  File "pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1998, in __init__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'table.csv'
[58900] Failed to execute script gui_calc

[Process completed]
```

My environment is:

Mac OSX 10.15.6

Python 3.7.7

pandas Version: 1.1.1

zsh 5.7.1

pyinstaller Version: 4.1.dev0

Comment: Did you copy the exe from `dist` folder to the project directory? I dont think `--add-data 'table.csv:.'` this will actually allow you to store the csv within in

Comment: This worked! But only when I execute the file via terminal in the file directory typing `./gui_calc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/14283616) pyinstaller in `--onefile` mode creates a temporary directory every time you run the executable and stores its path in `sys._MEIPASS` variable. When accessing the CSV file in your code, you need to refer to this path.

For example (modified code from answer I mentioned above):

```py
import os, sys

try: # running using executable
    path = sys._MEIPASS

except: # running using .py sript
    path = os.path.abspath('.')

csv_path = os.path.join(path, 'table.csv') # valid path of the csv file
```

For more info see: [How the One-File Program Works](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works), [Defining the Extraction Location](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#defining-the-extraction-location), [Run-time Information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information)

Comment: Thanks this worked! Better yet it makes my code portable for when I send it to other users.